# how to combine two views when they don't have the same count?

Tags: mysql

I created this ipview:
[image]

and this tcpview:
[image]

as you see the tcpview is smaller because some of cids doesn't have port so I wanted to combine these two views and when a cid doesn't have port make it empty in that field which operation should I take here and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`left join`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) tables and use [`ifnull`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to change `null` values to *empty*.

```
select i.cid, i.ip_src, i.ip_dst, ifnull(t.tcp_sport, '') as tcp_sport, ifnull(t.tcp_dport, '') as tcp_dport
from ipview i
left join tcpview t on i.cid = t.cid
```